# Udev rule for changing 'max_sectors_kb' for all 'sd*' devices

Tags: udev

I am having a problem creating a udev rule that sets max_sectors_kb to 1024 for sd* (sda,sdb,sdc etc...) devices under /sys/block/.

Specifically, a recent kernel change means the max IO is too large for my iSCSI SAN so I am trying to set it to 1024 on startup.

I have tried the following from articles online, but none seem to have an effect.

> ACTION==”add|change”, SUBSYSTEM==”block”, RUN+=”/bin/sh -c ‘/bin/echo
>   1024 > /sys%p/queue/max_sectors_kb’”

or

> ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}!="filesystem", ENV{ID_PATH}=="*-iscsi-*", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 64 > /sys$DEVPATH/queue/max_sectors_kb'"

When I run cat cat /sys/block/sdX/queue/max_sectors_kb the value is still the 32767 default.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in Proxmox VE 4.2 udev was failing to start at all.

This is why my rules were not applying.